# RF powered 3V LED

Tags: led, rf

Has anyone tried to create a RF power supply for a 3V LED over a distance of less than 1 meter? The LED  draws 20 mA.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you want to collect energy from radio waves in the air you will need a very large antenna. The Mythbusters tried to gather free energy from the air. They used a one-hundred foot antenna and only produced half of a volt. You would need six-hundred feet of wire for your antenna and it might work. This depends on the background radio wave radiation of wherever you are.

Answer (score 0):

Wireless power transfer has been used since Nikola Tesla's time and has continuously been explored in many forms through the years. This [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wireless_power_transfer) provides a great summary as well as references to known methods, which can even recharge an electric car through the garage floor via magnetodynamic coupling. Yes, voltages up to and far exceeding 3V have been achieved.